# How to convert a text into Bitmap image and put it onto a textview in android?

Tags: android

I have a Text like this--> 
String aa= "এন্ড্রয়েডের শুরু থেকেই এরসাথে রয়েছে গুগল টক। এতে সর্বশেষ সংযোজন হিসেবে ভিডিও চ্যাটের ব্যবস্থা যোগ করা হয়েছে।";. The String is in bangla. We can not display it directly without installing bangla font. But i want to display it without installing font. Is it possible to display the string as a bitmap image and then put into the TextView? If possible then how?
Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to set a background `Drawable` to a `TextView`, but this doesn't solve everything:

You could use the XML attribute `android:background="...your_image_resource..."` of your `TextView` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Or you could do it programmatically : `public void setBackgroundDrawable (Drawable d)`.

But:

- If this is an image, why to display it as the background of a `TextView` (that will contain no text)? It would be better to display it as an `ImageView` in that case.
- It is not possible to dynamically create the `Bitmap` of this text with the application as it would require to have the font installed to render the text in a `Bitmap`. And if the font is installed, there is no need to use a `Bitmap` to display it.

So, depending of your context:

- Either this text is fixed (like a logo or a catch phrase for example), in which case the best is to build your image from outside the application, to include it as a `drawable` resource and to display it as an `ImageView`
- Or it is not, in which case the user definitely needs to have the font installed on his/her device.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include a Bangla font in your apk and let the OS do the work for you?  http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/

Comment: i have tried this but in case of some complex character (ex. "ক্ষ","ত্ত") which is made of multiple fundamental characters(i.e. ক্ষ=combination of "ক", "্","ষ") it is not able to display the complex character instead display only the fundamental characters.

Comment: Ah, then Shlublu is correct, it seems you only have those two options.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer  [How to draw text On image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320392/how-to-draw-text-on-image/10313272#10313272)

[image]