# Android Drawing text onto a bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to write some text across a bitmap in Android. I've followed several guides and attempted several different code variations but I either get something obscure, a blank screen or the unaltered bitmap. This is the basic idea of what I've been playing around with.

```
public Bitmap writeOnDrawable(Context gContext, String path, String text) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPoint(30, 50, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Text", 33, 53, paint);

    return bmOverlay;
}
```

I pass this function the variables and then use the returned bitmap by turning it into a BitmapDrawable and making it a background of a layout. This particular version of the function returns only my initial, unaltered bitmap with no "Text" text across it.

I've attempted variations such as copying the original image:

```
Bitmap drawableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Drawing the original image onto the canvas:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(drawableBitmap, screenHeight, screenWidth, paint);
```

Comment: I think You should follow this link here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320392/how-to-draw-text-on-image

Comment: I've tried implementing solutions like those and end up with the same results. Using a few answers from that particular question I've ended up with the original image returning and a blank image.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using android-maps-util library.
add 
**compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'**
 dependency to your gradle file.
Use [IconGenerator](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) to create bitmap with text and use it in your BitmapDescriptor to create marker on your map.