# Android: Can we create bitmaps with Strings on it on the application runtime?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-runtime

I want to create a Bitmap with some string data on it, and later send it to my mobile printer.

How can we do that?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320392/how-to-draw-text-on-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawText("", 10, 10, paint);
//here you can return that bitmap directly
```

Comment: It worked but the background of the image is black (since the printer is white and black only). Can we set it to white?

Comment: Call `canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);` before calling `canvas.drawText(...);`.

Comment: How to make the text smoother? setting the canvas density? to what value/