# Canvas.drawText() changes text size for different size images

Tags: android, image, kotlin, canvas, android-canvas

I am drawing text on a `Bitmap`*(Image converted to Bitmap)* using the `Canvas` API `drawText()` method. I'm able to draw the text on the `Bitmap` but I am struggling to resolve the following error,

If the image is clicked from the device Camera, the text drawn over it is of the correct size. However, if some random image is selected from the gallery then the text drawn over it is way too large.

Here is the code for drawing text on Canvas,

```kotlin
            val scale = context?.resources?.displayMetrics?.density
            val textSizeInPixels = 44f

            val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
                          style = Paint.Style.FILL
                          color = Color.WHITE
                          setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE)
                          textSize = textSizeInPixels * (scale ?: 1F)
                       }

            val bounds = Rect()
            paint.getTextBounds(textToDraw, 0, textToDraw.length, bounds)

 
            //imagePath is of image either captured from camera or selected from gallery.
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(File(imagePath)))
            val x = bitmap.width.minus(bitmap.width.times(widthScale)) 
            val y = bitmap.height.minus(bitmap.height.times(heightScale))

            canvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, paint)
```

After debugging I recognized that the size of the camera captured image was `2176x3264 pixels` for this size, the text drawn on `Canvas` was correct. However some random image selected from gallery had a size of `914x1624 pixels` on which the text drawn was of huge size.

### How can I make sure, that irrespective of image size, the text size remains consistent?

#### I want both the images to have same text size.

Attaching the screenshots,

Image captured from device camera, the text drawn is of correct size
[image: Image captured from device camera, the text drawn is of correct size]



Image selected from the gallery, the text drawn is of large size.
[image]

This is the XML layout code for the `ImageView` on which I set the `Bitmap`.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_share_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_20"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_close">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_share_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but consider using [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout) instead of drawing text directly on the canvas. It is may give you more consistent results.

Comment: Also, how is the bitmap getting to the screen? I don't see that in the code you posted. Is the text and image getting stretch in the layout? Maybe an ImageView?

Comment: @Cheticamp, After drawing the text over bitmap. I set the bitmap on the `ImageView`. No, the image is not stretched, it fits well preserving its aspect ratio. Only the text is size is enlarged for different images.

Comment: I meant "stretched" as being resized. Since the two images appear to be the same size on-screen, then one or both are changing size. Since the source image you are having trouble with is smaller in width and height, it seems that it is being resized up so the text stretches especially since you are writing the text before placing it in the ImageView. Either resize the bitmap then write the text or place a TextView with a transparent background on top of the ImageView and write to it instead of the birmap.

Comment: Actually, stretching is not the real issue. If you check the width of the text that you are writing ('bounds.width' after ` paint.getTextBounds(textToDraw, 0, textToDraw.length, bounds)`) and adjusting for the write x coordinate. I think that you will see that it exceeds the width of your bitmap.

Comment: @Cheticamp after hours of debugging, I've one thing assured i.e the size of text is inversely proportional to the size of the image. If the image size is high, then the size of the text drawn is correct. However, if the image size is low, then the size of the text drawn is enlarged. I guess, we need some kind of scaling factor that can scale the text size depending on the image size. Got any clues ?